# Mostrar los documentos donde el array tenga más de x elementos

Tags: java, array, mongodb

Tengo mi bd en MongoDB y estoy intentando trabajar en Java.

Mi problema es que tengo un campo que es un array y me gustaria conseguir mostrar los documetos los cuales este array tiene mas de 3 elementos. en mongo la consulta seria:

```
db.companies.find({products:{$exists: true}, $where: 'this.products.length>3'});
```

Intento pasarlo a JAVAJavapero no encuentro como utilizar el `$where`

```
Document results = new Document("products", new BasicDBObject("$where", "this.products.length>3"));
MongoCursor<?> cursor = collection.find(results).iterator();
try {   
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next().toString());
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera de hacerlo es con la clase `com.mongodb.client.model.Filters`.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("miDatabase");
MongoCollection col = db.getCollection("miDatabase.companies");
MongoIterable iterator = col.find(
        Filters.and(
                Filters.exists("products"),
                Filters.where("this.products.length > 3")
        )
);
MongoCursor cursor = iterator.iterator();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    Document document = (Document) cursor.next();
    System.out.println(document);
}
```